# How to list a Array Multidimensional inside a table in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to list a multidimensional array inside an HTML table, but it didn't work as I wanted.

I'm gonna show the code below.

I've tried to put a `<br>` and `\n`.
One of them or both working together, but it didn't work.

THE ARRAY:

```
$data = array(
    array(0, 'John', 23),
    array(1, 'Junior', 14),
    array(2, 'Stevie', 42)

);
```

THE TABLE:

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>AGE</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <?php
            foreach ($data as $ind) {
                foreach ($ind as $i => $value) {
                    echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
                }
            } 
        ?>
    </tr>

</table>
```

THE RESULT:

```
ID  NOME    IDADE
0   John    23  1   Junior  14  2   Stevie  42
```

WHAT I EXPECTED:

```
ID  NOME    IDADE
0   John    23  
1   Junior  14  
2   Stevie  42
```

Comment: You need to surround the inner `foreach` with the `<tr>` and `</tr>` to get a new row each time.

Comment: What you mean would be it echo "<tr> <td>".$value."</td> </tr>"; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new row each time through the first loop:

```
<table>    
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>AGE</th>
    </tr>
        <?php
            foreach ($data as $ind) {
                echo "<tr>";  // start new row and loop and display columns
                foreach ($ind as $i => $value) {
                    echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>"; // end the row
            } 
        ?>
</table>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much my friend :)

Comment: @ijrdev please, also consider accepting this answer.

Comment: @ijrdev by the way, did you know that PHP accepts an [alternative syntax for control structures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) that might come in handy to gain in readability when dealing with heavily interlaced HTML/PHP code?